# jQuery UI Menu widget and frames (menu being cut off)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am helping a company with an old web application, that uses frames. I am trying to add a **jQuery UI Menu** to the top frame (x is where the menu should go, f are frames):

```
------------
|    f    x|
------------
|  |       |
|  |   f   |
| f|--------
|  |       |
|  |   f   |
------------
```

I am using the following code to show the menu, and this technique works well with **jQuery UI Dialog** widget to get them to show "above" the frames. For some reason though it does not work for the **jQuery UI Menu** widget. It does not show the menu "above" the frames (see screenshot below):

```
(function () {
    window.showUserMenu = function () {
        var rootWindow = window.top;
        if ((rootWindow !== window.self) && rootWindow.showUserMenu) {
            return rootWindow.showUserMenu();
        }
        else {
            $('#userMenu').show().position({ my: "right center", at: "right center", of: "#userName" });
        }
    };
})();
```

The problem in this code is that the `window` object contains the `showUserMenu()` function, but the `window.top` (or `rootWindow`) object does not. That results in that it does not recusively call `showUserMenu` on the top window (`rootWindow`), even though the first part of the if-statement is true. Unfortunately I am not skilled enough in Javascript to understand why it does not work in this scenario, when it works for the dialogs.

In my mind, if `window` has the method `showUserMenu`, then so should `window.top` or `rootWindow`, right?

Screenshot of the menu being "cut off" by the frame:

[image: menu "cut off" by frames]

Comment: _"In my mind, if window has the method showUserMenu, then so should window.top or rootWindow, right?"_ - no, why? It would totally depend on whether the top window itself also got a function by that name added to it, or not.

Comment: Then why does this code work for the Dialogs, in the same application, with the same frame layout? In that case, the code recursively walks up the tree and shows the dialog over the entire web page. How can it do that if the `showDialog` function does not get inherited to all windows, using pretty much exactly the same code?

Comment: How could we possibly know, with the rudimentary info given so far? Maybe that `showDialog` function _was_ added to all window objects.

Comment: Well, then, how do you add a function to all window objects? Maybe there is some code that I have missed in this huge application, that does something to all windows. I thought that the above code was telling **all** window objects to get this function, but obviously I am incorrect about that.

Comment: That function you got there checks if the top window _does_ have such a function, and if so, it assigns that as function of the same name to the current window; if not, it _creates_ a new function to show the menu, for the current window.

Comment: Hmmm, I think that I have completely missunderstood how this function works. But given your last comment, I might figure out how to solve this. Thanx!